# non-negative s-measurable functions on a finite measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Assume that $(X,s,\mu)$ is a finite measure space and $f,g$ are non-negative $s$-measurable functions such that $fg \ge 1$ a.e. Show that $(\int f \,d\mu) (\int g \, d\mu) \ge (\mu(X) )^2$

This inequality is clearly true if either integral is infinite, so I am looking for a solution for the finite case. I have an answer, but it does not depend on anything that we have recently covered, so I am pretty sure I am missing something big. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use Hölder's inequality:
$$\mu(X)=\int_X \sqrt{1} \mathrm d \mu\leq\int_X \sqrt{f}\sqrt{g} \mathrm d \mu\leq\left(\int_X f \mathrm d \mu\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_X g \mathrm d \mu\right)^{1/2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, I looked at it again, and it made sense... I don't know what I was missing.